# Bad underbrace with fourier-otf

Tags: math-mode, fonts, underbrace, fourier

As per the title, `\underbrace` looks bad with `fourier-otf`. I'm not sure how to explain it with words, so here's a picture of a MWE:

[image]

I think the best way to describe it might be that the underbrace "starts too late". I was wondering if this was a solvable problem, a known one, or just how the font looks. Thank you all in advance.

Utilizing `\underbracket` does not exhibit the same "behavior":
[image]

I am compiling with `latexmk -lualatex`. Here's the source-code of that MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,fontspec,fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
    \[ \underbrace{A'X'}_{Y'} = DAC^{-1}X' \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could be even worse: try `\underbrace{AX}`

Comment: That _is_ worse. Is this an issue with the font then?

Comment: It might be an issue with `unicode-math` (and possibly LuaTex), as it's not restricted to the `fourier-otf` font family.

Comment: For `fourier` , and a compilation with `pdflatex`, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You see a similar thing even in classic text with `\left\{` fonts have a small numbr of glyphs for the first few sizes which gives curlier nicer looking braces before switching to an extensible form with straight extension pieces inserted, but it does mean that they are only available in discrete sizes.

You could use the next larger size, but it's a bit big or just move the existing one to the left a bit to compensate for the visual appearance of A taking up more of the baseline than X'

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,fontspec,fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
    \[ \underbrace{\:A'X'}_{Y'} = DAC^{-1}X' \]
    \[ \underbrace{\,A'X'\,}_{Y'} = DAC^{-1}X' \]
\end{document}
```

Or you could use the brace from a smaller font so it is already in the extension range although I'm not sure I like the effect

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,fontspec,fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
    \[ {\scriptstyle\underbrace{\textstyle A'X'}_{\scriptstyle Y'}} = DAC^{-1}X' \]

\end{document}
```

Of the three I'd use the first, I think.

Comment: Is there a way to ask for the extensible braces from the get-go?

Comment: @PurpleMyst not really, basically tex asks the font for a delimiter of  a certain size and the font does what it does, tex has no conrol over that.